I cannot install any tool
I have installed free download manager on my Ubuntu computer to try some downloading but they did not work, so I wanted to delete it.
I ran the dpkg command to remove it and that's it.
now whenever I want to install package I get this error and I can't install anything.

I have tried also update and apt --fix-broken install but it doesn't work either.
Here are all commands that I have tried.


The error message tells you that you are missing some packages that you should install first -- did you try that?

yes i did. I tried them all but i always receive the same error over and over again.

yes. it doesn't work either

I think the issue here is that dpkg itself does not resolve dependencies (nor conflicts) - that's what higher-level tools like apt are for. You appear to have installed a 32-bit version of jdk-19 that must be removed before dpkg will be able to install anything.

Please go through your /var/log/apt/history.log and find all packages from the i386 architecture (which is 32-bit) that you have installed, and remove them.

I have checked that and there is no i386 package @Jos
